# updating a database using a table adapter and data table

Tags: vb.net

I am currently working on a VB program connected to an Access database.  I have fill a data table using a query and data adapter.  At a later stage in the program, i want to go through and make permanent changes to the database using the adapter and table.  I tried this:

```
For Each row As DataRow In db.DBDT.Rows

            row("fldsentda") = "Y"
            row("flddasenddate") = Date.Today
        Next row


        'db.DBDT.AcceptChanges()
        db.DBDA.Update(db.DBDT)
```

*db is a class file, dbda is the data adapter, and dbdt is the data table

but i realized these changed are only effected the data table and not the actual database.  How can I get it to where it will effect only the database rows that are inside of the data table filled using the query?

Update: I'm thinking my update function isn't written. I don't know if this should be a separate question or not, but how do I write the update function to only change fields in the database that has been changed on the data table??

Comment: use the dataadapter to send the changes to the db - `myDA.Update(myDataTable)`  As you sort of stumbled upon, you can store any number of adds/deletes/changes in the datatable and update the DB all at once (and economically).

Comment: thank you for your comment.  is that any different from the last line, "db.DBDA.Update(db.dbdt) "??

Comment: get rid of `AcceptChanges` that doesnt do what you think it does

Comment: yes.  I was following a tutorial and "db" is a class file used to control the database.  It has the connection.  thank you.  will do (get rid of...).

Comment: that "helper" class may cause problems later (depending on what it does).  Connections should be created, used and disposed of in the smallest scope possible.  Global connections can work, but actually are harder to manage

Comment: Got you. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Do not call

```
db.DBDT.AcceptChanges()
```

before

```
db.DBDA.Update(db.DBDT)
```

Doing so marks everything in the datatable as not changed. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges(v=vs.110).aspx) especially in remarks section.

Just call the update method and the acceptchanges should be called automatically for you.